# Cropping, Re-sizing and Saving images from one folder to another folder in wordpress

Tags: php, image-processing, wordpress, resize-crop

I'm adding an upgrade for the WordPress plugin which I have developed ages ago. This plugin is just a product catalog, so just show products and their images. Products can have more than one images.

I was re-sizing images in the older version of the plugin by CSS, assigning them width and height. Which was working but images look stretched but users were happy. Now I have added a new feature in the plugin which is to crop and re-size from the uploaded image and save it with a different name, like a thumbnail.jpg.
The new feature is working remarkably for the new users who upload images, but the thing is about old users who upgraded to newer version.

The issue is old users already has products and images. When I try to get all the products and images via `foreach` loop, it works perfectly on 200 - 250 images but breaks on more than 250+ images - No Error :(

Many of my old users has 600+ images so I want a way to crop and re-size the existing images and saves them with a new name and save the file names in the DB.

I'm using wordpress's default `wp_get_image_editor();` function.

Here's my query to get old products which has images:

```
$wpc_product_images_sql = "Select wpc_posts.*, wpc_meta.* From " . $wpdb->posts . " As wpc_posts Inner Join " . $wpdb->postmeta . " As wpc_meta On wpc_posts.ID = wpc_meta.post_id Where wpc_meta.meta_key = 'product_images' Order By wpc_posts.post_title;
```

And here's my `foreach` loops (I'm using two loops. First one is getting the products which has images and the second loop is for get images from each post, as I'm mentioned earlier in my question that products can have more than one images. So have to use two loops)

```
foreach ($wpc_images_qry as $wpc_prod_images) {

                echo '<div class="wpc_image_body">'
                . '<h3>' . $wpc_prod_images->post_title . '</h3>'
                . '<div class="wpc_images">';

                $wpc_post_id = $wpc_prod_images->ID;
                $wpc_product_images = get_post_meta($wpc_post_id, 'product_images', true);

                $big_img_name = array();
                foreach ($wpc_product_images as $wpc_prod_img) {
                    /// For Big
                    $big_resize_img = wp_get_image_editor($wpc_prod_img['product_img']);
                    if (!is_wp_error($big_resize_img)) {
                        $product_big_img = $wpc_prod_img['product_img'];

                        $product_img_explode = explode('/', $product_big_img);
                        $product_img_name = end($product_img_explode);
                        $product_img_name_explode = explode('.', $product_img_name);

                        $product_img_name = $product_img_name_explode[0];
                        $product_img_ext = $product_img_name_explode[1];

                        $big_crop = array('center', 'center');
                        $big_resize_img->resize($wpc_image_width, $wpc_image_height, $big_crop);
                        $big_filename = $big_resize_img->generate_filename('big-' . $wpc_image_width . 'x' . $wpc_image_height, $upload_dir['path'], NULL);
                        $big_resize_img->save($big_filename);

                        $big_img_name[]['wpc_big_img'] = $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $product_img_name . '-big-' . $wpc_image_width . 'x' . $wpc_image_height . '.' . $product_img_ext;


                        if (file_exists($upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $product_img_name . '-big-' . $wpc_image_width . 'x' . $wpc_image_height . '.' . $product_img_ext)) {

                            echo $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $product_img_name . '-big-' . $wpc_image_width . 'x' . $wpc_image_height . '.' . $product_img_ext . ' - <strong style="color: #7ad03a;">OK</strong><br>';

                        } else {
                            echo $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $product_img_name . '-big-' . $wpc_image_width . 'x' . $wpc_image_height . '.' . $product_img_ext . ' <strong style="color: red">:(</strong><br>';
                        }
                    }

                }
                update_post_meta($wpc_post_id, 'wpc_big_images', $big_img_name);

                echo '</div>'
            . '</div>';
            }
```

Comment: Is this to do with the server timing out when the script takes too long to run (this is often set at about 30 seconds). If it works on 200 - 250 images can you do them in batches of 200 - 250 images?

Comment: It might be a server timeout issue... So what are your suggestions about batching the images in php?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding the new image size with
[add_image_size()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)
and then run
https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/
which surely has a solution to the timeout problem.
There is a way to display a message for your plugin users upon update, ask them to install and run the plugin if they have old images.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resize image mean follow these one, it resize your image whenever upload image in media,

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','aj_handle_upload');

function aj_handle_upload($file)
{

    add_image_size( 'mobile', 360, 0, array( 'center', 'center' ));//mobile is userdefined name.    
    add_image_size( 'desktop', 700, 0, array( 'center', 'center' ));//desktop & tablet is user defined name.    
    return $file;
}
```